# A same class/module/orwhateveritis multiple times

Tags: puppet

Puppet must hate me. I have been reading the doc for hours on end and still cannot manage to achieve the following:

- a class or module (or what is it called) with a variable in it (a parameterized class?);
- this class to be included multiple times in a single host.

In pseudo-code, that would be:

```
# The class
classorwhatever myclass ($value) {
    notify { "$value world" }
}

# In the node definition
node whatever {
    myclass("Hello")
    myclass("Goodbye")
}
```

I feel so stupid it is not even funny. I know it *must* be doable. But how? :(

Comment: You are reading this? http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/modules2.html. What vrsion of puppet is on your server/client?

Comment: @Zoredache 2.6.12 on both the server and clients

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only use a parameterized class once. If you plan to hit a node several times with a function while varying the data definitions are the way to go.

example

```
class apache ( $module ) {
  if module = ssl then and so on
}

define apache::vhost ($priority=99) {
  file { "apache/vhost.d/${name}":
    content => template("apache/vhosts/$name.erb"),
  }
}

node webserver {
  class { 'apache': module => 'ssl', }
  apache::vhost { 'www': priority => 00, }
  apache::vhost { 'test': priority => 99, } 
}
```

Comment: Excellent. fwiw #puppet on freenode and the mail lists are very active and have covered things like this in depth. If you're just getting started with Puppet I'd suggest keep both those resources on hand.